# Translation not working with Poedit & Php

Tags: php, gettext, poedit

I've been trying with the following code to translate using Poedit & PHP. It's a very basic example which I'm trying to translate in German language. I've files in the following folders.

```
/home/test/test.php
/home/test/localization.php
/home/test/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/default.po
/home/test/locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/default.mo
```

test.php

```
require_once("localization.php");
echo _("Hello World!");
```

localization.php

```
$locale = "de_DE";

if (isset($_GET["locale"])) 
    $locale = $_GET["locale"];

putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");

setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);

bindtextdomain("default", "./locale");

textdomain("default");
```

When I run `localhost:8080/test/test.php`, It shows only english message `"Hello World!"`. I've translated in `default.po`. Here it is:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: a\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-01-29 09:37+0530\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2014-01-29 09:38+0530\n"
"Last-Translator: Rahul <rahul@gmail.com>\n"
"Language-Team: b <a@b.com>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Poedit-KeywordsList: _;gettext;gettext_noop\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"X-Poedit-Language: German\n"
"X-Poedit-Country: GERMANY\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: .\n"

#: test.php:4
msgid "Hello World!"
msgstr "Hallo Welt!"
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try ``bindtextdomain("default", dirname(__FILE__)."/locale");`` instead of ``bindtextdomain("default", "./locale");``

Comment: What dirname & __FILE_ in this scenario? Is it LC_MESSAGES & default.po?

Comment: @ub3rst4r. Still not working.. I gave the same.. bindtextdomain("default", dirname(__FILE__)."/locale");

Comment: I know this is an old question, but have you checked that the `de_DE` locale is installed on your server? And that your PHP was built with the `--with-gettext` option?

Comment: If you're on linux machine run command locale -a to see what languages are installed on your system. Also instead of locale='de_DE' maybe you need exact name locale='de_DE.utf8' as installed on linux.,